# Import 3D model to Xcode with its nodes

Tags: swift, xcode, 3d, scenekit

I have **3D Models** which have many parts and are designed by some 3D editors such as: AutoCad, Blender... 
Those **3D Models** are combined many parts, so I want to import them to Xcode with same parts, then add Node to each part.
I want to interact with each part in **ScenceView**.

> 3D model from:
>   https://drive.google.com/file/d/11MccUtXd61wDWQldMTleotvg_yoHnzWP/view?usp=sharing

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As i can see on the link provided by you, the 3D model is available in FBX and OBJ formate. for using in Xcode you can try using following steps.

1. Convert your model into DAE or .SCN formate. (you can use Blender) .DAE and .SCN formate contains all the nodes in a single file.
2. import your Model with associate texture folder in the art.scnassets folder.
3. Load and use your model.

Comment: Are there other ways to work with .OBJ formate without converting it before loading it? Thanks

Comment: Yes you can load OBJ files as well. but you can't import that file in art.scnassets filder. just do following steps.

1. Drag and drop OBJ file into your project. 
2. Get path of your file. and convert it to SCNscene.(Code Below)
      
  let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()  
        let path = bundle.pathForResource("genrator", ofType: "obj")  
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)  
        let asset = MDLAsset(URL: url)  
     
        let scene = SCNScene(MDLAsset: asset)

Comment: But the 3D model doesn't contain its child nodes